# Spring Integration Exception ignoring container setting on int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter

Tags: spring-integration

As per my understanding, Runtime Exception in ServiceActivator should send message to errorChannel.

But if errorHandler is not set then that doesn't work. I even tried to set errorHandler

```xml
 <bean id="translatorContainer"    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
            <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
        <property name="errorHandler" ref="myErrorHandler"/>
        <property name="destination" ref="TRANSLATED-MDCAD" />
        <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />
        <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="50" />
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1" />
        <property name="receiveTimeout" value="5000" />
        <property name="recoveryInterval" value="60000" />
        <property name="autoStartup" value="false" />
    </bean>

<int:channel id="TRANSLATED-MSG-CHANNEL"/>

<bean id="TRANSLATED-MDCAD" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="TRANSLATED-MESSAGE-QUEUE" />
</bean>

<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
    id="MDB-TRANSLATED" 
    channel="TRANSLATED-MSG-CHANNEL" container="translatorContainer" acknowledge="transacted"/>


<int:service-activator input-channel="IN-MSG-CHANNEL"
    output-channel="TRANSLATED-MSG-CHANNEL" ref="myProcess"
    method="execute" />
```

But on RuntimeException in myProcess (ServiceActivator) then i am seeing following in log

```java
WARN : [2014-03-16 00:11:51.219] org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.
org.springframework.integration.MessagingException: failed to handle incoming JMS Message
    at org.springframework.integration.jms.SubscribableJmsChannel$DispatchingMessageListener.onMessage(SubscribableJmsChannel.java:164)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:561)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:499)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:467)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:325)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:263)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1059)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:948)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I have debugged DefaultMessageListenerContainer, JmsMessageDrivenEndpointParser and some other internal class and found that container is getting set correctly.

BUT when exception is thrown, it is using default container ( not the one i have set on int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter : translatorContainer which has errorHandler set )

What could be the reason? Is there any other alternate setup I can try to redirect runtime exception to errorChannel? Let me know if you need more information

I am using spring integration version 2.2.5

#### DETAIL CONFIG

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:int-jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd        
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms.xsd
        ">


    <bean id="connectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
        <property name="hostName">
            <value>${mq_hostname}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="port">
            <value>${mq_port}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="queueManager">
            <value>${mq_queuemanager}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="channel">
            <value>${mq_channel}</value>
        </property> 
        <property name="transportType" value="1" />
        <property name="useConnectionPooling">
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
    </bean>




    <int:annotation-config />

    <int:message-history />


    <bean id="defaultMessageListenerContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="destination" ref="DEBATCHED-MDCAD" />
            <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    <property name="errorHandler" ref="manifestErrorHandler"/>
     <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />
    <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="50" />
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1" />
    <property name="receiveTimeout" value="5000" />
    <property name="recoveryInterval" value="60000" />
    <property name="autoStartup" value="false" />
</bean>
    </bean>

    <bean id="translatorContainer"  class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="destination" ref="TRANSLATED-MDCAD" />
            <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    <property name="errorHandler" ref="manifestErrorHandler"/>
    <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />
    <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="50" />
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1" />
    <property name="receiveTimeout" value="5000" />
    <property name="recoveryInterval" value="60000" />
    <property name="autoStartup" value="false" />
</bean>
    </bean>




    <!-- Global Channel Interceptor -->
    <int:channel-interceptor ref="metadataInterceptor"
        pattern="*CHANNEL" order="1" />

    <int:wire-tap pattern="*CHANNEL" order="1" channel="logger" />



    <int:gateway id="manifestGateway"
        service-interface="gov.dhs.cbp.manifest.oceanexport.gateway.ManifestGateway" error-channel="ERRORS-MSG-CHANNEL" /> 

    <int:logging-channel-adapter id="logger"
        level="ERROR" log-full-message="true" />

    <int-jms:channel id="INBOUND-MSG-CHANNEL" queue-name="INBOUND"  error-handler="manifestErrorHandler"/>



    <int:channel id="DEBATCHED-MSG-CHANNEL" />

    <bean id="DEBATCHED-MDCAD" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
        <constructor-arg value="DEBATCHED" />
    </bean>



    <int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
        id="MDB-DEBATCHED" 
        channel="DEBATCHED-MSG-CHANNEL" container="defaultMessageListenerContainer" acknowledge="transacted"/>

    <bean id="manifestErrorHandler" class="gov.dhs.cbp.manifest.process.util.ManifestErrorHandler"/>



        <int:channel id="TRANSLATED-MSG-CHANNEL"/>

    <bean id="TRANSLATED-MDCAD" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
        <constructor-arg value="TRANSLATED" />
    </bean>


    <int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
        id="MDB-TRANSLATED" 
        channel="TRANSLATED-MSG-CHANNEL" container="translatorContainer" acknowledge="transacted"/>


    <int:channel id="ERRORS-MSG-CHANNEL" />

    <bean id="ERROR-EXTERNAL" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
        <constructor-arg value="ERRORS" />
    </bean>


    <int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="ERROR-EXTERNAL-ADAPTER"
        channel="ERRORS-MSG-CHANNEL" destination="ERROR-EXTERNAL" />



    <int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="ERROR-CHANNEL-EXTERNAL-ADAPTER"
        channel="errorChannel" destination="ERROR-EXTERNAL" />





    <!-- ## Service Activator ## -->
    <int:service-activator input-channel="DEBATCHED-MSG-CHANNEL"
        output-channel="TRANSLATED-MSG-CHANNEL" ref="manifestProcess"
        method="execute" /> 


    <!--  DEBATCHER - SPLITTER -->
    <int:splitter input-channel="INBOUND-MSG-CHANNEL"
        output-channel="DEBATCHED-MSG-CHANNEL" ref="debatcherService"
        method="execute" />



    <!-- RESPONSE SERVICE / NOT ROUTER DUE TO BUSINESS LOGIC -->
    <int:service-activator input-channel="TRANSLATED-MSG-CHANNEL" ref="responseService"
        method="generateResponse"/>

    <bean id="pool"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="8" />
    </bean>

<!--
<bean id="retryTemplate" class="org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate">
    <property name="retryPolicy">
        <bean class="org.springframework.retry.policy.SimpleRetryPolicy">
            <property name="maxAttempts" value="4" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="backOffPolicy">
        <bean class="org.springframework.retry.backoff.ExponentialBackOffPolicy">
            <property name="initialInterval" <value="1000" />
            <property name="multiplier" value="5" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
-->

</beans>
```

#### USING RETRY template to solve the issue

```xml
<bean id="retryTemplate" class="org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate">
    <property name="retryPolicy">
        <bean class="org.springframework.retry.policy.SimpleRetryPolicy">
            <property name="maxAttempts" value="1" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="backOffPolicy">
        <bean class="org.springframework.retry.backoff.ExponentialBackOffPolicy">
            <property name="initialInterval" value="1000" />
            <property name="multiplier" value="5" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>


    <int:service-activator input-channel="DEBATCHED-MSG-CHANNEL"
        output-channel="TRANSLATED-MSG-CHANNEL" ref="manifestProcess"
        method="execute" >  
         <int:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice">
            <property name="recoveryCallback">
                <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer">
                    <constructor-arg ref="errorChannel" />
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="retryTemplate" ref="retryTemplate" />
        </bean>
    </int:request-handler-advice-chain>
    </int:service-activator>
```

Answer (score 2):

As we see by your StackTrace the issue is around `SubscribableJmsChannel` (`<int-jms:channel id="fooChannel" queue-name="foo"/>`), where you don't use a custom `container`.

But you show a config for `<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>`.

So, be careful analyzing the issue.

Now, if you want the same behaviour for `<int-jms:channel/>` you can inject your `myErrorHandler` to the channel's property `error-handler`

Comment: My setup
1)GATEWAY( INBOUND-JMS-CHANNEL )
2)SPLITTER (input : INBOUND-JMS-CHANNEL output: SPLITTER CHANNEL )
3)SERVICE ACTIVATOR( input: SPLITTER CHANNEL output: TRANSLATED CHANNEL )
4)SERVICE ACTIVATOR ( input: TRANSLATED CHANNEL ) code base routing to output channel

Comment: Runtime Exception is in SERVICE ACTIVATOR where i don't have any jms-channel . Runtime Exception on step 3 puts message back in step 1. Why? INBOUND message channel is int-jms:so as per your suggestion, i added errorHandler and now error handler is getting invoked but message still goes  back to INBOUND ORIGINAL QUEUE rather than removed from it. Is this configuration wrong? So basically message is going in loop. Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Please show the correct configuration (and all of it).Clearly the stack trace is from a different flow. What do you mean GATEWAY(INBOUND-JMS-CHANNEL)? An jms:channel is not a gateway. Why are you using a channel instead of a channel adapter to start the flow? Channels are not designed for that purpose.

Comment: Your message is returned to the queue, because JMS is transactional by nature. `ErrorHandler` just a hook to get deal with that error, but it doesn't help to keep `commit` for the problematic message. You should you should 'strangle' the exception somewhere in your service-activator to allow for JMS transaction to be commited.

Comment: @GaryRussell I have added detail config in original message. GATEWAY's request channel is INBOUND-JMS-CHANNEL.Actually gateway is used for testing. External system going to write message to INBOUND queue so i am going to change it to message driven channel adapter. For current scenario, i have tried changing to adapter and result is same.

Comment: @ArtemBilan Thats true. We make many DB calls in service activator which needs to be part of transaction. If i handle exception to remove message from original queue then DB TX will need to be rollback manually. That will be ugly so trying to find better option.

Comment: For testing, instead of changing the inbound adapter to a jms channel (which is diffferent) for `INBOUND`, have the gateway send the message with an outbound adapter to `INBOUND`. Then, use a message-driven adapter for INBOUND and add an error-channel and handle the exception there.

Comment: @ArtemBilan  I am going to use retry template to redirect message to error channel. I am updating original question area with detail about how i have setup retry template.